# Google maps work locally but not online.

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I cannot find out why Google Map works perfectly local but not online.
Check it: www.giacomobartoli.xyz at the end of the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to put all relevant code into your question or it'll likely be closed.

Comment: you have not provided  a valid apikey for google maps .. could be this don't let you use the maps on internet ..

Answer (score 2):

When you use firebug you can see in your console following warning message:

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

[Google says:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?hl=de)

> The script element that loads the API has no API key. Please make sure
>   you include a valid API key as a key parameter. You can generate a new
>   API key on the Google Developers Console.

So you just need to include a valid API key.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the jquery.min.map file and also the marker image file. Please check your sources and try again.
change `jquery.min.map` to `jquery.min.js` 
Also get a key in google's [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)